# Answer for very simple maths game is always Wrong - Python

Tags: python, math, if-statement, python-3.x

here is my script:

```
from random import *
from turtle import *

while True: 
    r1 = randint(1,20)
    r2 = randint(1,20)

    # ... ask the question ... then

    a = textinput("Answer?", "")

    if a == r1 * r2:
        write("Well done", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 30, "bold"))
    else:
        write("WRONG", font = ("Comic Sans MS", 30, "bold"))
```

The game is very simple. It picks too random numbers and asks you to multiply them. You get the answer right your score goes up. Get the answer wrong your score goes down. When I input the right answer it still comes up "Wrong"
I think maybe I'm doing the ifs differently or it might not be working 
because of the random numbers. Has anyone got an idea what is wrong with my script. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to upvote edits? @PhilH does a great job here.

Comment: @eumiro: Well, except that he removed the import that made `write()` mean something...

Comment: @Wooble - `write` wouldn't mean much without the whole initialization and since this has nothing to do with the error (which apparently has been discovered), I think it is clearer now.

Comment: Does it make me a bad person that I wanted to downvote for Comic Sans? :)

Comment: Turtle is back in now. Finding the problem is 90% of solving it. I was tempted to change the code, but I drew the line at merely removing unnecessary stuff.

Comment: Incidentally, to any beginners, don't `from X import *`. It pollutes the namespace with anything and everything in the libraries. Use `from random import randint` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`r1 * r2` is an integer.

`a` is a string.

Convert `a` to integer and compare.

Converting to integer is simple:

```
s = int(a)
```

However, a `ValueError` can be raised and has to be handled.

Comment: The `ValueError` doesn't *have* to be handled; this isn't Java. It is perfectly valid to assume inputs are sane if the reaction when that doesn't hold is to blow up (rather than introduce a potential security flaw).

Comment: I'm not sure how this works. When I have s = int(a) it gives me a wrong answer and subtracts 10 from the number I inputed and ads it to my score

Comment: @DennisCallanan - maybe you're using `s` elsewhere? Give it a different name.

Comment: Actually I misunderstood what you were saying. I'm after doing it right now and it works perfectly. Thank you :)